# I can't figure out a way to find a specific char in a stringbuilder and replace it with uppercase

Tags: java, char, stringbuilder, uppercase

For Example:
Enter a String:
aAaAaAaAaAaAbBbBbBbBbBbBbcCccccCCccCCCC

What character should be converted to uppercase?
b

What the output should be:
aAaAaAaAaAaABBBBBBBBBBBBBcCccccCCccCCCC

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(keyboard.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Which character should be converted to uppercase?");
    char c = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

    ParsingUtils.changeLetter(sb, c);

    System.out.println(sb);
}

public static void changeLetter(StringBuilder sb, char letter)
{
    String change = Character.toString(letter); //changes the char in the parameter to string
    String change2 = change.toUpperCase(); //make an uppercase copy of the string
    char upper = change2.charAt(0); //change the upper case copy to a char

    for (int counter = 0; counter < sb.length(); counter++) //Is supposed to replace every instance of the given character with uppercase
    {
        if (sb.toString().contains(change))
        {
            sb.setCharAt(counter, upper);
        }
    }
}
```

What my code outputs: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBcCccccCCccCCCC

Is there a better, less convoluted way to do this that I'm too frustrated to see?

I'm still a novice in Java so there is probably a simple answer that is going completely over my head.

Comment: You can use `sb.charAt(counter)` to look at a single character.

Comment: For a more efficient loop, you can use `sb.indexOf(change, startIndex)` to jump directly to the next occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The first three lines can be simplified to just:

  ```
  char upper = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
  ```
- Use `charAt(counter)`, rather than checking if the whole string builder contains the letter.

  ```
  if (sb.charAt(counter) == letter)
  ```

Full code:

```
public static void changeLetter(StringBuilder sb, char letter)
{
    char upper = Character.toUpperCase(letter);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < sb.length(); counter++)
    {
        if (sb.charAt(counter) == letter)
        {
            sb.setCharAt(counter, upper);
        }
    }
}
```